# How can I execute a command until the end of the file in vim?

Tags: vim

I have something that looks like:

```
{
hey1
},
{
you2
},
{
hey3
},
{
you4
}
```

And I want to change it to:

`{hey1},
{you2},
{hey3},
{you4}`.

I know I can make a macro like `qa 3Jj q` then do `103@a` but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to 1) Make a macro and 2) know the line count.  So I was trying something like: `3J . G.` but that doesn't work.  How can I execute the 3J command on every 3 lines till the end of the file?

Comment: you say you want to do 3J on each set of 3 lines, but your desired output it all of the lines joined.  which are you looking for?

Comment: sorry about that I've updated the question

Answer (score 5):

You can execute `j!3` (join three lines, starting with the current one, with no extra spaces) on every line that starts with `{` using the `:global` command:

```
:g/^{/j!3
```

You get exactly the same result (on your sample text) if you try to do the same on every line (ignoring the first character) since `:g` knows enough not to try to perform a command on a line that is not there anymore:

```
:g/^/j!3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can join the lines with the following command:

```
:%j!
```

Udpate: If by any chance you would like to use the macro, you can run it on whole file using

```
:%normal  @a
```

Comment: The question was ambiguous (now edited); that's not what the OP wanted.

Comment: Ohh! I looked at the previous desired output and answered this.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an explicit loop that stops when it reaches the last line:

```
:while line('.') < line('$') | exe 'normal! 3Jj' | endwhile
```

Or you could just rely on the command sequence aborting when there are no more lines, and create a sufficiently long sequence:

```
:exe 'normal!' repeat('3Jj', 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're not adverse to making a macro, you still don't need to know the line count. You could do 999999@a and it will stop on the last line anyway, since the 'j' command to go to the next line will error out and abort the rest of the command. Or, you could record a recursive macro to do the same thing: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Record_a_recursive_macro